# Magento2.1.6 : admin filters are not trimming the white space

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

Once we add something for filtering ended with white space, search results are not  displayed even the data is present.Can we have trim function and if yes then how?

Comment: The issue in Magento default or custom module? because default Magento already trimming after and before.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya no its the issue of default magento 2.1x versions, trimming is done in 2.2x versions.

Comment: You should upgrade your magento 2.X to 2.2.x is good option. :)

Comment: its not feasible for now..thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Is that issue only for product grid filter or the same issue in other grid?

Comment: I guess filtering is working from one source only so its obvious to get this error to every filters like products, customers, CMS pages, Blocks and everywhere filter feature is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the module and override the filter.js as below.

**1. Create requirejs-config.js under**

> **Namespace\Module\view\base\requirejs-config.js**

with below code. **(Don't use adminhtml/base as it's a base file)**

```
var config = {
      "map": {
        "*": {
          "Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/filters": 
              "<Namespace>_<Module>/js/grid/filters/filters"
        }
      }
    };
```

**2. override filter.js to below path.**

> **Namespace\Module\view\base\web\js\grid\filters\filters.js**

added latest versions js as below.

```
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
**/

/**
* @api
*/
define([
   'underscore',
   'mageUtils',
   'uiLayout',
   'uiCollection',
   'mage/translate',
   'jquery'
], function (_, utils, layout, Collection, $t, $) {
   'use strict';

/**
 * Extracts and formats preview of an element.
 *
 * @param {Object} elem - Element whose preview should be extracted.
 * @returns {Object} Formatted data.
 */
function extractPreview(elem) {
    return {
        label: elem.label,
        preview: elem.getPreview(),
        elem: elem
    };
}

/**
 * Removes empty properties from the provided object.
 *
 * @param {Object} data - Object to be processed.
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function removeEmpty(data) {
    var result = utils.mapRecursive(data, utils.removeEmptyValues.bind(utils));

    return utils.mapRecursive(result, function (value) {
        return _.isString(value) ? value.trim() : value;
    });
}

return Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'ui/grid/filters/filters',
        stickyTmpl: 'ui/grid/sticky/filters',
        _processed: [],
        columnsProvider: 'ns = ${ $.ns }, componentType = columns',
        bookmarksProvider: 'ns = ${ $.ns }, componentType = bookmark',
        applied: {
            placeholder: true
        },
        filters: {
            placeholder: true
        },
        templates: {
            filters: {
                base: {
                    parent: '${ $.$data.filters.name }',
                    name: '${ $.$data.column.index }',
                    provider: '${ $.$data.filters.name }',
                    dataScope: '${ $.$data.column.index }',
                    label: '${ $.$data.column.label }',
                    imports: {
                        visible: '${ $.$data.column.name }:visible'
                    }
                },
                text: {
                    component: 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    template: 'ui/grid/filters/field'
                },
                select: {
                    component: 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
                    template: 'ui/grid/filters/field',
                    options: '${ JSON.stringify($.$data.column.options) }',
                    caption: ' '
                },
                dateRange: {
                    component: 'Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/range',
                    rangeType: 'date'
                },
                textRange: {
                    component: 'Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/range',
                    rangeType: 'text'
                }
            }
        },
        chipsConfig: {
            name: '${ $.name }_chips',
            provider: '${ $.chipsConfig.name }',
            component: 'Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/chips'
        },
        listens: {
            active: 'updatePreviews',
            applied: 'cancel updateActive'
        },
        statefull: {
            applied: true
        },
        exports: {
            applied: '${ $.provider }:params.filters'
        },
        imports: {
            onColumnsUpdate: '${ $.columnsProvider }:elems',
            onBackendError: '${ $.provider }:lastError',
            bookmarksActiveIndex: '${ $.bookmarksProvider }:activeIndex'
        },
        modules: {
            columns: '${ $.columnsProvider }',
            chips: '${ $.chipsConfig.provider }'
        }
    },

    /**
     * Initializes filters component.
     *
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'updateActive');

        this._super()
            .initChips()
            .cancel();

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Initializes observable properties.
     *
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    initObservable: function () {
        this._super()
            .track({
                active: [],
                previews: []
            });

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Initializes chips component.
     *
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    initChips: function () {
        layout([this.chipsConfig]);

        this.chips('insertChild', this.name);

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Called when another element was added to filters collection.
     *
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    initElement: function (elem) {
        this._super();

        elem.on('elems', this.updateActive);

        this.updateActive();

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Clears filters data.
     *
     * @param {Object} [filter] - If provided, then only specified
     *      filter will be cleared. Otherwise, clears all data.
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    clear: function (filter) {
        filter ?
            filter.clear() :
            _.invoke(this.active, 'clear');

        this.apply();

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Sets filters data to the applied state.
     *
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    apply: function () {
        this.set('applied', removeEmpty(this.filters));

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Resets filters to the last applied state.
     *
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    cancel: function () {
        this.set('filters', utils.copy(this.applied));

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Sets provided data to filter components (without applying it).
     *
     * @param {Object} data - Filters data.
     * @param {Boolean} [partial=false] - Flag that defines whether
     *      to completely replace current filters data or to extend it.
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    setData: function (data, partial) {
        var filters = partial ? this.filters : {};

        data = utils.extend({}, filters, data);

        this.set('filters', data);

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Creates instance of a filter associated with the provided column.
     *
     * @param {Column} column - Column component for which to create a filter.
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    addFilter: function (column) {
        var index       = column.index,
            processed   = this._processed,
            filter;

        if (!column.filter || _.contains(processed, index)) {
            return this;
        }

        filter = this.buildFilter(column);

        processed.push(index);

        layout([filter]);

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Creates filter component configuration associated with the provided column.
     *
     * @param {Column} column - Column component whith a basic filter declaration.
     * @returns {Object} Filters' configuration.
     */
    buildFilter: function (column) {
        var filters = this.templates.filters,
            filter  = column.filter,
            type    = filters[filter.filterType];

        if (_.isObject(filter) && type) {
            filter = utils.extend({}, type, filter);
        } else if (_.isString(filter)) {
            filter = filters[filter];
        }

        filter = utils.extend({}, filters.base, filter);

        return utils.template(filter, {
            filters: this,
            column: column
        }, true, true);
    },

    /**
     * Returns an array of range filters.
     *
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    getRanges: function () {
        return this.elems.filter(function (filter) {
            return filter.isRange;
        });
    },

    /**
     * Returns an array of non-range filters.
     *
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    getPlain: function () {
        return this.elems.filter(function (filter) {
            return !filter.isRange;
        });
    },

    /**
     * Tells wether specified filter should be visible.
     *
     * @param {Object} filter
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    isFilterVisible: function (filter) {
        return filter.visible() || this.isFilterActive(filter);
    },

    /**
     * Checks if specified filter is active.
     *
     * @param {Object} filter
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    isFilterActive: function (filter) {
        return _.contains(this.active, filter);
    },

    /**
     * Checks if collection has visible filters.
     *
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    hasVisible: function () {
        return this.elems.some(this.isFilterVisible, this);
    },

    /**
     * Finds filters whith a not empty data
     * and sets them to the 'active' filters array.
     *
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    updateActive: function () {
        var applied = _.keys(this.applied);

        this.active = this.elems.filter(function (elem) {
            return _.contains(applied, elem.index);
        });

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Returns number of applied filters.
     *
     * @returns {Number}
     */
    countActive: function () {
        return this.active.length;
    },

    /**
     * Extract previews of a specified filters.
     *
     * @param {Array} filters - Filters to be processed.
     * @returns {Filters} Chainable.
     */
    updatePreviews: function (filters) {
        var previews = filters.map(extractPreview);

        this.previews = _.compact(previews);

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Listener of the columns provider children array changes.
     *
     * @param {Array} columns - Current columns list.
     */
    onColumnsUpdate: function (columns) {
        columns.forEach(this.addFilter, this);
    },

    /**
     * Provider ajax error listener.
     *
     * @param {bool} isError - Selected index of the filter.
     */
    onBackendError: function (isError) {
        var defaultMessage = 'Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the ' +
                'filter to its original state.',
            customMessage  = 'Something went wrong with processing current custom view and filters have been ' +
                'reset to its original state. Please edit filters then click apply.';

        if (isError) {
            this.clear();

            $('body').notification('clear')
                .notification('add', {
                    error: true,
                    message: $.mage.__(this.bookmarksActiveIndex !== 'default' ? customMessage : defaultMessage),

                    /**
                     * @param {String} message
                     */
                    insertMethod: function (message) {
                        var $wrapper = $('<div/>').html(message);

                        $('.page-main-actions').after($wrapper);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
});
```

**3. Run below commands**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: You shouldn't copy latest versions `filters.js` file, because, it may affect to other functions or functionality. Kindly replace that  `removeEmpty` function in new override file.

Comment: You can try magento 2 js mixin, that is best way to override only one function of core JS.